# Как получить background color пикселя на странице

Tags: javascript, canvas

Хочу получить цвет заднего фона логотипа при скроллинге и если он достаточно темный, svg красить в белый цвет. Я пробывал нарисовать прозрачный 1px canvas и брать цвет его заднего фона, но он мне возвращает (0,0,0,0)
Как можно реализовать аналог color picker для страницы?

Comment: ну Вы бы привели свой код

Comment: Предлагаю определять цвет элемента под логотипом по другому, например через getComputedStyle()... то что Вы хотите получить - скорее всего не возможно, т.к. это была бы дыра в безопасности